# Drawing with matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix

How can I draw the function x+y=n with n not greater than 10 and the coordinate system using only matrices without any functions or libraries? I am a beginner and I hope you could help me.

```
      #include<stdio.h>
       int main() {
       int n,i,j;
       scanf("%d", &n);
       char m [12][63]={" "};
       for(i=0;i<12;i++){
           for(j=0;j<63;j++){
           m[i][j]=' ';
         if(i==0 && j==1) m[i][j]='0';
         if(i==11 && j==61) m[i][j]='2';
         if(j==0 && i!=0 && i!=11) m[i][j]='0'+10-i;
         if(j==2 && i!=11) m[i][j]='+';
         if(i==11 && j%3==2) m[i][j]='0'+((j-2)/3)%10;
         if(i==11 && j%3==1 && j>29 && j<59) m[i][j]='1';
         if(i==10 && j%3==2) m[i][j]='+';
        if(j==3*(n+i-10) && i>2 && j>2)  m[i][j]='*';       
    }
}        
   for(i=0;i<12;i++){
       for(j=0;j<63;j++){
           printf("%c", m[i][j]);
       }  printf("\n");
       }
      }
      //my code doesn't print the correct result(the coordinate system is correct except that it prints 0+ instead of 10+ on y axis and x+y=n is not correct

      0+                                                            
     9 +                                                            
     8 +                                                            
     7 +                                                            
     6 +                                                            
     5 +                                                            
     4 +                                                            
     3 +                                                            
     2 +                                                            
     1 +*                                                           
     0 +  +* +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
       0  1  2* 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: What is `x` in `m[j][i] = x - 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of what you were trying with those conditions. Check this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

int main() {
    
    int n;
    char m[N][N];
    
    while( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 && n > (N-1)/2 );
    
    memset(m, ' ', N*N);

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        
        m[i][0] = '*';
        m[i][i] = '*';
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < (n-1)*2; i++) m[n-1][i] = '*';
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        for(int j = 0; j < (n-1)*2; j++) printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program could be improved, it wastes a lot of memory and prints a lot of unnecessary blank spaces. Try to improve it by reducing the unused portion of the matrix. In this way you will also reduce the unnecessary prints.

Comment: But, I actually need to draw the picture with pluses and numbers, everything from picture should be in my result

Comment: Just modify the program

Comment: Do I hava to write the numbers from 1 to 19 one by one to put them in the matrix or is there any faster way? I mean, do I have to write m[0][1] =1... one by one?

Comment: No you don't have to. Just play with the index `i`. For this particular case `m[i][0] = i+1` should do the trick. The `0` indicates the first column, while `i` switch along the rows. Just play around to get confident with this row/col system and everything will be all right

Comment: I tried that before, but I got some question marks and a lot of numbers

Comment: Oh I am sorry, since `m` is not an array of `int` but an array of `char` to put a digit inside it you need to add the character `0` to the digit. So you need to do `m[i][0] = i + 1 + '0';`. Note that the other statement `m[i][i] = '*';` will overwrite the previous when `i == 0`. Have fun.